# Simplify a Combinatorial Sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a\choose k}{b\choose c-k}{d-k\choose e}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there a way to simplify
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a\choose k}{b\choose c-k}{d-k\choose e}$$
where $a,b,c,d,e$ are natural numbers?

In particular, I would like to see the case for $a=45, b=3,c=4,d=48,e=4$.

Comment: Assuming $\binom{n}{m}=0$ whenever $n<0$, $m<0$ or $m>n$, this sum simplifies to
$$\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{a}{k}\binom{b}{c-k}\binom{d-k}{e},$$
where $m=\min\{0,c-b,d\}$  and $n=\min\{a,c,d-e\}$.

Comment: @Servaes: I wrote the infinity summing bound precisely to save from having to write out $m$ and $n$ as you define it for the terms outside the boundary vanishes as you have indicated. So this is not the simplification I am seeking.

Comment: You tagged this with generating functions - is that the kind of simplification you want to see? I doubt it will be of much help unless you plan to use a CAS to get coefficients.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: I want to ask if generating function may be of help to simplify this sum, perhaps by turning it into a coefficient of some term of an expression. What is the CAS? It would be helpful not to use acronyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series can be cast into hypergeometric form and is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{c-k} \binom{d-k}{e} = \binom{b}{c} \binom{d}{e} \, {}_{3}F_{2}(-a, -c, e-d; -d, b-c+1; 1)
\end{align}
Further reduction may be possible depending on the values of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

**Proof of result**
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{c-k} \binom{d-k}{e} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{b! \, \Gamma(a+1) \Gamma(d+1-k)}{k! \, \Gamma(a+1-k) \Gamma(c+1-k) \Gamma(b-c+1+k) \, e! \, \Gamma(d-e+1-k)} \\
&= \frac{b! \, d!}{e! \, c! \, (b-c)!} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-a)_{k} (-c)_{k} (e-d)_{k}}{k! \, (-d)_{k} (b-c+1)_{k}} \\
&= \binom{b}{c} \binom{d}{e} \, {}_{3}F_{2}(-a, -c, e-d; -d, b-c+1; 1).
\end{align}
It is to be noted that $b-c+1 \neq 0,-1,-2, \cdots$ and $d \leq 0$.

---

As given by the example values $a=45, b=3,c=4,d=48,e=4$ the series is best handled in a straight forward manor. 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{45}{k} \binom{3}{4-k} \binom{48-k}{4} &= \sum_{k=1}^{4} \binom{45}{k} \binom{3}{4-k} \binom{48-k}{4} \\
&= 45 \, \binom{47}{4} + 3 \cdot 45 \cdot 22 \, \binom{46}{4} + 3 \, \binom{45}{3} \binom{45}{4} + \binom{44}{4} \binom{45}{4} \\
&= 27,061, 623, 270. 
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful. Could you please explicate the derivation? Also, I have added a specific example of the parameter. Will it admit further reduction?  Otherwise, if the hypergeometric function is still expressed as a sum, it does not seem to reduce the complexity of computation, but only append a (fancy) name to the left hand side. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Hans  The additional work has been added. There are conditions for the reduction of hypergeometric series. In the example values provided the conditions are not met. What is more applicable is a straight forward calculation.

Comment: So there is no reduction of computational complexity in either the general case or the special case, right? It is nice to make the connection with the generalized hypergeometric function though.